# Erro na instalação do Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Sempre que estou tentando instalar o visual studio 2015 no meu notebook, aparece o seguinte erro :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

alguem saberia como resolver ??

Comment: Você precisa realmente utilizar o VS2015? Se não sugiro começar com o mais atualizado que é o VS2017 Community: https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.br%2F

Comment: sim, precisa ser a 2015 ... preciso resolver esse erro, mudar a versao da ide não ta em cogitação

Comment: Teria como entrar no log que ele sugere e colocar aqui o conteúdo?

Answer (score 1):

Após pesquisar um pouco verifiquei que o instalador pode ter feito confusão na hora de instalar bibliotecas x86 e x64. Há algumas formas de se resolver o problema, vou citar duas:

### 1ª opção

**1.** Após o erro na instalação, feche o instalador.
**2.** Entre no painel de controle e depois nos programas instalados.
**3.** Repare todos os `Microsoft Visual Redistributable`, tanto a versão `x86` quanto a `x64`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A imagem acima representa os que eu tenho instalado. Pode ser que você não tenha a mesma quantidade ou tenha outros nomes. **Repare todos** que tenham `Microsoft Visual Redistributable` no nome. Sim, isso pode levar um tempo para ser concluído.

**4.** Execute o instalador do Visual Studio.

### 2ª opção

**1.** Desinstale completamente o Visual Studio 2015 do seu computador.
**2.** Desinstale todos os `Microsoft Visual Redistributable`, tanto a versão `x86` quanto a `x64`.
**3.** Reinicie o computador.
**4.** Manualmente delete as `dlls` que possam ter ficado no computador de ambas as pastas system32 e SysWOW64 (os nomes das `dlls` acabam com *140.dll - **tenha cuidado e faça um backup antes!**)
**5.** Faça o download do "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3" desse link - https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=53840 - ambas as versões `x86` e `x64`.
**6.** Instale o "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update 3" - ambas as versões `x64` and `x86`.
**7.** Reinicie o computador.
**8.** Execute o instalador do Visual Studio 2015.